# How would you use つもり with する verbs? のつもり or するつもり?

Tags: syntax

Is it more correct to say:

> 勉強のつもり
>   or
>   勉強するつもり?

EDIT:
I take it 'I plan not to study' would be 「勉強しないつもり」. Unless it's something else like 「無勉強のつもり」 which I highly doubt. Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: Recall that を is omitted in 勉強する. Whether or not 〜するつもり is natural is a different question.

Comment: 勉強のつもり means that you regard what's not supposed to be 勉強 as 勉強.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

つもり has mainly two meanings. The one means "be going to do" and the other means "intention that you consider something as real something, though they aren't real or not doing in real". https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/148367/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A4%E3%82%82%E3%82%8A/

A plain form of a verb + つもり means the former one. For example, 私は明日勉強するつもりです (I am going to study tomorrow).

A noun or a progressive form of a verb + つもり means the latter one. For example, when you pick up a broom, you can say "これはギターのつもり" and then you can pretend to play the guitar, while you say "ギターを弾いているつもり". And they also mean "I intend that I am doing (something as something)", for example, 私は彼とけんかしているつもり would be translated as "I intend that I am quarreling with him."

勉強のつもり means the latter one. 勉強しないつもり is natural and we don't say 無勉強のつもり.

Comment: So the second meaning is like, to pretend to? Or to pretend something is something? So i guess a case might be you are preparing for a sports match and discussing tacting and are using figurines and a board or something and you say 'this will be our striker' 「ストライカーのつもりです」

Comment: Both types of つもり can be thought of as corresponding roughly to the English "intend". 勉強するつもり is "I intend to study" whereas for instance 冗談のつもりで言った is "I intended it as a joke". The latter usage is more flexible than the English "intend", hence things like けんかしているつもり and 勉強のつもりでやっている are natural even though we wouldn't usually say "I intend that I'm fighting with him" or "I intend this as studying" in English, but it's the same basic usage.

Comment: @I dunno what to call myself  It is hard for me to describe it correctly in English, but your example is good.

Comment: @ Ben Roffey Thank you for your advice. I edited.

Answer (score 2):

You'd use するつもり. However, keep in mind that つもり is used to express intent. For example, 明日日本語を勉強するつもりです is acceptable if you mean to express intent to "study Japanese tomorrow". But, this sets the precedence that it's a do-or-die situation, as opposed to something you're casually planning to do.

You might say 明日日本語を勉強するつもりです if you mean to say that all of your volition is behind studying tomorrow and for good reason. You may not say that about grabbing pizza with friends in the afternoon, though:

> 今日３時ごろ友達とピザを食べるつもりです。 << This is wrong! It's too strong a tone.

Instead, try:

> 今日３時ごろ友達とピザを食べる**予定{よてい｝があります。**

Apologies in advance for bad examples. I seem to be particularly lacking in that department...!

Comment: 「今日３時ごろ友達とピザを食べるつもりです。」ってそんなにおかしいと思えないんですけど・・

Comment: @Chocolate 確かにね。　でも、「今日何するんですか」とか聞いた場合、「するつもり」より「予定」のほうはいいではありませんか？　つまり、"I intend to eat pizza with my friends around 3:00pm." が「つもり」を使うはいいだけど、それより "I have plans to eat pizza with my friends around 3:00pm."　っていう「予定」を使うのほうが自然ではありませんか？

Comment: 「今日何するんですか？」って聞かれたら「3時ごろ友達とピザ食べます。」って答えるかも・・。ところで「つもり」と「予定」はちょっと意味・ニュアンスが違う場合があるのでは・・「友達とピザを食べる予定」はちゃんと友達と約束してそうだけど、「友達とピザ食べるつもり」は自分の心の中でそうしようと勝手に思ってるだけかも。。　「つもり」って自分でそう思ってる（だけ）みたいな感じだけど、「予定」は外的要因も関係してきそうな。。。

Comment: 日本語の先生はこういう説明しました：　「つもり」は、自分の心の中で決めた、だからそうします。　それって言えるけど、ピザやへ友達と会いに行って、友達が来ない場合はどうしますか？　また、友達に「今日は３時ごろピザをたべようよ」とかその計画ちゃんと立ちましたか？　だから、人間関係で話している場合だったら、「つもり」より「予定」を使ったほうがいいです。

つまり、文法や言葉は違わないんだけど、@Chocolateが言ったとおりニュアンスは違いますね？